# updating ClamAV 0.98.7 to 0.99.0 for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: updates, clamav

I would like to update my ClamAV antivirus 0.98.7 to 0.99.0 and tried updating it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clamav
```

After which I got a message:

> your clamAV is the newest version?

But when I tried updating the signature database by typing `sudo freshclam`, I got the message `your clamav 0.98.7 is outdated`.

I was able to download the ClamTK GUI and was able to update my definitions to the current one but my anti-virus engine is outdated. I tried downloading the 0.99.0 from the clamav website and unpacked the compressed files. When I ran ClamAV using ClamTK, it found 4 threats and the files from the uncompressed ClamAV 0.99.0 were infected.

*Is there a way I can allow Synaptic Package manager to locate the software center package of the latest version?*

I set up ClamTK to notify me any Antivirus engine updates. I was able to get rid of the infected files. I normally get software updates via package update manager.
I have a server version of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS running a GUI version on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** It is normal to find infected files in the downloaded application, as they put them in there for test files that you can test with.

---

I just updated mine to 0.99.0 with a little bit of configuring for the new version.

First, I downloaded the [0.99.0 version](http://www.clamav.net/downloads/production/clamav-0.99.tar.gz) from [here](http://www.clamav.net/downloads).

Went to the Downloads folder

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

then ran

```
tar zxvf clamav-0.99.tar.gz
```

to extract all the files.  Went to the extracted folder

```
cd clamav-0.99/
```

Had to install openssl part

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Then ran

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

After it was installed, I had an issue with the `freshclam` updater.  I had to follow an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/553322/231142) I wrote before to fix the `clamav-freshclam` updater.

```
terrance@DV7-UBUNTU:~$ clamscan --version
ClamAV 0.99
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the response. When running ./configure, make, then sudo make install, which directory I have to be in?

Comment: @MannyL. You should be in the extracted directory of `clamav-0.99/` It will probably be in your `~/Downloads` where the file should have been downloaded to