# How to install the latest clamav?

Tags: 15.04, clamav

There is a warning in my country that this trojan infected computers over a news site (The Trojans name is GOZI).

I used `clamav` but it says it is not the latest version.

How to install the latest version of `clamav`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed)

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a virus and it's not really that question.

Comment: A trojen is a virus and your question can be broken down to "How do I install anti-virus" anti-virus software is how you would check if you have a virus.

Comment: There are several listed only on external sites. But most I don't find in the software store. Which one do you suggest? I installed ClamTk, which has a terrible user GUI (I can't figure out how it works).

Comment: Use the command line version `clamav`, it will be installed already run `sudo freshclam` to update the database, then `sudo clamscan -r /` to run a scan, when it is done it will list `threts` it finds on your computer.

Comment: See here for more detail http://askubuntu.com/questions/250290/how-do-i-scan-for-viruses-with-clamav

Comment: Thanks. It says I'm using an outdated version, how can I update it? P.S. I already did `sudo apt-get update`, but the same error shows up.

Comment: You can't from the repos, that is the version you get. If you add `how to install the latest clamav` to the question, I will write you an answer on how to build it from source but it needs to be in the question or it will just get flagged and removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall `clamav` and `clamtk` repository version:

```
sudo apt-get purge clamav clamtk
```

First you will need some dependencies and build tools:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl build-essential libssl-dev checkinstall
```

Download this file, it will go to your `/home`:

```
wget https://www.clamav.net/downloads/production/clamav-0.99.1.tar.gz
```

Extract that file and change to the folder it created:

```
tar -xvzf ~/clamav-0.99.1.tar.gz
cd ~/clamav-0.99.1
```

Now run the following commands to build `clamav 0.99.1`:

```
./configure
make
```

Now build a package with

```
sudo checkinstall
```

`checkinstall` will guide you through the building of a `.deb` package and when it is done run

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/clamav-0.99.1/clamav_0.99.1-1_amd64.deb
```

Now it is installed but you may face errors about a config file, if you do run these commands (Thanks to user [Terrance](https://askubuntu.com/users/231142/terrance) on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526317/cant-run-freshclam) for this, if you use it give him a vote)

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure clamav-freshclam
```

Just keep pressing Enter to use default settings, then run

```
sudo rm -f /usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf
sudo ln -s /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf /usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf
```

Now you can run a

```
sudo clamscan -r /
```

To do a scan.

Tested on 15.10.

Comment: After the installation I receive:
`clamscan: error while loading shared libraries: libclamav.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` when trying to run `nuc@nuc:~/clamav-0.99.1$ sudo clamscan -r /`

Comment: I got that error too. Forgot to add to the question sorry. Run ` ldconfig` in a terminal and reboot, I think that was the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from http://www.govcert.admin.ch/blog/21/20min.ch-malvertising-incident

The infection chain is as follows:

1. The swf file on 20min.ch contains an embedded Javascript which does a basic fingerprint using User Agent and Cookie. Based on this information a decision is made whether to redirect to the infection site or not.
2. Redirect to the exploit Kit where a VB Script is downloaded with another check which exploit would suit the target
3. Infect the device with Gozi in the form of a .dll that is made persistent via registry key (rundll) under HKEY\CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run. The dll resides in the %APPDATA% folder of the user.

Comment: ...what is the conclusion of your "answer"?