# Scanning External Drives for Viruses - Ubuntu

Tags: security, malware, antivirus

So I recently installed Ubuntu onto one of my Computers and would like to uses it to scan external drives USB and what not for viruses that can affect windows PC. Is there a possible antivirus or antimalware detection tool i can use on Ubuntu to look for Viruses/Malware that can affect windows or MacOS computers?

Comment: I agree with the dup here, but sometimes the freshclam updater may not work properly.  If so, please check the answer here:  https://askubuntu.com/a/553322/231142